# Use journalctl to show logs of specific unit which has a parameter?

Tags: systemd, systemd-journald, journalctl

I have one systemd service which runs with `systemctl --user start test_unit@random_arguments`. How could I use `journalctl` to filter all logs of `test_unit`? If it supports "follow mode", that's even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a user unit, use the [`--user-unit`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journalctl.html#--user-unit=) option:

```
journalctl -f --user-unit=test_unit@random_arguments
```

Otherwise, filter the unit with `_SYSTEMD_UNIT`:

```
sudo journalctl -f _SYSTEMD_UNIT=test_unit@random_arguments
```

Comment: Thanks. The `--user` option saves my day.  `journalctl --user -u test_unit@* -f` works

Comment: Right, `--user-unit` combines `--user` and `-u` ;-).